# Not able to pull the SQlite database file from Eclipse file explorer

Tags: android

I am not able to pull a SQLite database file from the directory `data/data/package/database`.
I gave up pulling the file from the device, but it's showing:

> failed to pull the section

How do I fix this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative to PUSH:

: Emulator has to be open && Browse in Terminal/CommandLine to ".../android_sdk/tools"

Syntax: " adb push   "

Answer (score 0):

Unless the device is rooted you cant access the data folder. Try using the emulator.